# Managed VMs running Perl on Google App Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a perl job that runs for 5 mins at the top of every hour.  What is the most cost effective way of running this job on the Google Cloud infrastructure?  Running a compute engine VM seems too heavy-weight for this since I'd get charged for the other 55 mins of no use.  I don't understand the "Managed VMs" well enough, but it seems like this might be an option, but I'm not sure if pricing is rounded to the hour.  Does anyone have any ideas what the best option is so that I only get charged for 120 mins of usage (24 times run * 5 minutes). The script also uses some image processing binaries, so converting to Python won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) are linked to Google App Engine. If you have an App in GAE, managed VMs are used to configure the hosting environment for you App using VMs that run on Google Compute Engine and these applications are subject to Java and Python run time. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#time_granularity_instance_pricing) can give you an idea on pricing on GAE, however Perl is not a [supported language in GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#language).

On GCE, you can start up an instance, do the task and then delete the instance without deleting the persistence disk, this will allow you to recreate the instance using this disk, however you will still be charged for the [provisioned disk space](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#disk) and you will need to create a script that will spin up the instance and delete it. You can also create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#applying_snapshots) of your disk and recreate your instance based on the snapshot, this will be little bit less expensive that keeping the disk.

Also, you should look at the type of [persistence disks](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/compute-engine-disks-price-performance-and-persistence/) (PD) on GCE, at this link, take a look at the examples provided, since based on your operation, regular PD or SSD PD can make a big difference on price.

You can use the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to estimate your charges

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to App Engine using a managed VM, an compute engine instance (managed by google) is created for you. All request to App Engine will be forwarded to the created compute engine instance.

To run your script in App Engine as a Managed VM, you will have to dockerize your project, as the managed VM runs a docker container.

I don't see a reason to use App Engine managed VM (just for running a script), as the cost will be same as using a compute engine instance.

Probably the most cost effective way is to create a script that:

> Launches a compute engine instance
>
> Install perl
>
> Copies your script to the instance
>
> Runs you script in the created instance

To schedule the execution, you can put at home/office a cron job that executes the above script.